Merged vector layer - batch fill cells in attribute table
I have two vector layers i've merged, each with many MANY polygons (58,500 in total for both...). However, I want to be able to fill in missing cells.
Specifically, I have one field (class_desc) that was perfect on one layer, but empty on another. This matches to code_18 field. So i'd like to be able to batch fill the class_desc to match the code. So, 111 is continuous urban fabric... however, there are numerous classes! Is there a way to tell QGIS to say "all rows with code_18 as 111 should have class_desc as continous urban fabric; every 112 = discontinuous urban fabric etc etc.
